# Why is the article "die" used before "neben". Are there instances where other articles are used?

Tags: preposition, german-to-english, pronoun, gender

In the explanation:

> Es gibt aber auch einige Verben, die neben dem Subjekt (im Nominativ) auch ein Dativobjekt verlangen.

I am not sure why *die* is used.

Answer (score 4):

> Es gibt aber auch einige *Verben*, *die* neben dem Subjekt (im Nominativ) auch ein Dativobjekt verlangen.

Here, *die* is not an article but one of many [German relative pronouns](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen), similar to *which*, *that* and *who* in English. In the example sentence, it refers back to the plural noun *Verben* in the main clause.

Answer (score 2):

"Es gibt aber auch einige Verben, **die** *neben* dem Subjekt (im Nominativ) auch ein Dativobjekt verlangen."

"Yet there are some verbs **which** also demand [..] *besides* [...]"

"die" is a reference to "[die] Verben" - as "Verben" is plural, any other gender would get the same treatment. Not so in the singular (*das* Verb, die Verben; *der* Mann, die Männer; *die* Frau, die Frauen): e.g.: "Es gibt aber einen Hund, **der** neben Knochen auch Spinat verlangt". (= "Yet there is a dog **which** also demands spinach besides bones")

See 'relative pronouns':
http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/pronouns/relative-pronouns/

Comment: At least the term *relative pronoun* should be mentioned for further reference and research.

Comment: @guidot done, thanks!